# unable to find "bring to front" and "send to back" option in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, panel

I am new to Visual Studio 2013.

I am using a single form with two panels where the second panel is stacked on top of the first. I am unable to switch to the first panel. I have searched Google and also looked for answers here as well. They all suggest using the "Bring to Front" and "Send to Back" options, but I cannot find them anywhere.

Comment: right click the panel, and the option should be there?

Comment: If you just want to select the panel for editing in the designer then right click over the first panel. You should see a "select secondpanel" menu. Click on it and you could edit its properties. Instead if you want to use the second panel to add controls then use the Menu FORMAT -> Order -> Bring/Send

Comment: I am using WINFORM @Sajeetharan

Comment: I am able to select the panel but i cannot bring it front with its content like button.

Comment: post your layout, will try to modify

Answer (score 8):

Goto Design Mode **View->Designer**, Right Click the Panel You want to bring to front and Click **Bring To Front** ,

[image]

Comment: It is not always possible to right click, if a control is at the back completely covered by another control for example

Answer (score 7):

You can also go to the Document Outline Window and drag your Controls into the right order. 
You can find it under View -> Other Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can select the control in the properties window. Then click the design window to put focus on it. Press Shift + F10 to bring up the context menu. From there you can select "Send to Front"

Answer (score 0):

Right Clicking Bring to Front should bring the panel to front, However you must make sure that the panel you are right clicking is the outer panel not a panel within another panel, Always check the properties window to see which panel is selected.

Also check View > Other windows > Document outline to make sure that the panel you want to view is on the same level as the one you selected.