# How to bring back c# controls whose Text property were deleted and are not visible in the Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have a `Label` over the TextBox for which I deleted the Text Property. Now it is not visible. How to bring it back to visibility?

[image]

I want to move the label control. That's why I need to see the control. Please tell me how to make it visible in the form.

Comment: You can add text property again, so it will be visible again.

Comment: find label with empty text in the Designer.cs file and put some value

Comment: I want to move the label control. That's why I need to see the control. Please tell me how to make it visible in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're unable to find or select a control in the designer, you can still find it in the "Document Outline" window. To access this window in Visual Studio, go to:

View -> Other Windows -> "Document Outline" Window

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `Label` from the top of the `Properties Window` in ComboBox.
After you select it, You can change the `Location` value for move it.

Other way is select `Label` on `Document Outline Window` and move it manually.

But easiest way is fill the `Text` value and move it ,then clear the `Text` again!

Answer (score 0):

there a buttons called `bring to front` and `send to back`,
here how u can get them

[unable to find "bring to front" and "send to back" option in visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323104/unable-to-find-bring-to-front-and-send-to-back-option-in-visual-studio-2013)